# How can we use both SkuType.INAPP(One-time products) and SkuType.SUBS for subscriptions in one Android Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I want to use both one-time product(SkuType.INAPP) and subscriptions(SkuType.SUBS) on my Android application.
I'm wondering how can we implement both at once.

Answer (score -1):

Setup your products i.e.One time purchase and subscriptions on your Google Play console account and refer this documentation [Integrate the Google Play Billing Library into your app](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)

Comment: I did those configurations from play console and I used recurring subscriptions before in my app, But now I want to use non-recurring one time purchases together with subscriptions.

Comment: what do you mean together? @AravindaR.

Comment: Together means i want to do purchases by both, one time and recurring at one screen. My main concern is how can I initiate both from app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297987/8851971 refer this

Comment: The user asks for a way to use both INAPP and SUBS in his Android app, not how to setup to use INAPP or SUBS in the Google Play console.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a complete solution. It's just to give you an idea of how you can solve your problem.

If you would like to use both INAPP and SUBS at the same time in your app you must call the Billing API twice to get two SkuDetailsLists and handle the items individually within your app.

When BillingClient is ready do this:

```
    if (billingClient.isReady()) {
        getSkuDetailsListInapp();
        getSkuDetailsListSubs();
    }
```

Handle the logic for each case. Keep two skuDetailsLists, one for SUBS items and one for INAPP items.

Then, when the user select an item to purchase/subscribe to in your app you provide the correct list to handlePurchase.

Make sure you handle the logic for both SUBS and INAPP payments within handlePurchase. You might need to consume INAPP items for example.

Comment: Really poor API design on Google's part...